# How can i use bootstrap4 pop ups and modals in Angular 6 Project

Tags: css, angular, model, bootstrap-4, mean-stack

**Angular.json**

```
"styles": [        
      "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                        "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
                        "src/styles.css"
                    ],
                    "scripts": ["../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
                        "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
                        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
                    ],
```

I want to use bootstrap modal in my angular project but i am not able to do so, even though i npm all the modules and imported tham in angular.json file but Bootstrap Model is not working.

**Modal Code in Component.html**

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
Launch demo modal
 </button>

<!-- Modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
       <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm.. I am currently using Ng-bootstrap instead of the 'original' bootstrap. Works much better for Angular projects, imo. Plus it doesn't require Jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using ng-bootstrap they have a [Modal](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples).
Click [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) for installation instructions. And [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples) for an example [Modal](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples)